# BlackBerry application auto login

Tags: blackberry

I want my BlackBerry application login to have a "remember me" check box. If the user is logged in with that checkbox clicked, then the user can auto-login next time.

Answer (score 1):

For that you have to use persistence data store.  The Blackberry Developer Knowledge Base has a good article about this: [Storing persistent data](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Storing-persistent-data/ta-p/442747)

Answer (score 1):

use persistence store to store your details.